# ¿Cómo separar los datos de un ArrayList con valores delimitado por comas?

Tags: java, xml, csv, arraylist, file

El primer ArrayList contiene:

- Hola
- adeu

El segundo:

- 1,2
- 2,3
- 3
- 4,5,6,7

  ---
- ArrayList lineasFicCabecera = new ArrayList();
- ArrayList lineasFicDatos = new ArrayList();

DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

```
        // Elemento raiz
        Document doc = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("doc");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        for (int i = 0; i < lineasFicDatos.size(); i++) {
            String contadorNr = "" + i;

            // Contenido
            Element elem = doc.createElement("elem");
            rootElement.appendChild(elem);

            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("nr");
            attr.setValue(contadorNr);
            elem.setAttributeNode(attr);

            for (int j = 0; j < lineasFicCabecera.size(); j++) {
                Element dato = doc.createElement(lineasFicCabecera.get(j));
                dato.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lineasFicDatos.get(j));
                elem.appendChild(dato);
            }
        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("archivo.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("\nEl documento xml se ha generado correctamente!");
```

La salida seria como en la imagen pero no consigo separar los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé con la función split pero salta el error.

```
for (int j = 0; j < lineasFicCabecera.size(); j++) {
                Element dato = doc.createElement(lineasFicCabecera.get(j));
                dato.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lineasFicDatos.get(j).split(",")));
                elem.appendChild(dato);
            }
```

¿Alguien que me ayude con esto?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Mautista pero tienes un ejemplo de como son inicialmente los datos?

Comment: Hola, te explico tengo dos ficheros: el primero que es formato .txt y dentro tengo dos lineas que son: linea1) hola  || linea2) adeu y las guardo en el ArrayList(lineasFicCabecera); el segundo fichero es formato csv, en el guardo  linea1) 1,2   ||  linea2) 2,3  ||  linea) 3    || linea4) 4,5,6,7  y los guardo en ArrayList(lineasFicDatos)  @Jorgeys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo creo que vas bien con Split. Pero split retorna un arreglo de String.

Luego necesitas que por cada indice del listado de cabecera uses el mismo indice en el arreglo retornado. Además tienes que considerar que hacer cuando la cantidad de datos sean mas que la cantidad de cabeceras.

```
    String datos[] = lineasFicDatos.get(i).split(",");
    for (int j = 0; j < Math.max(lineasFicCabecera.size(), datos.length); j++) {
        Element dato;
        if(j < lineasFicCabecera.size()){
            dato = doc.createElement(lineasFicCabecera.get(j));
        } else {
            dato = doc.createElement("altre");
        }

        dato.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(datos[j]));
        elem.appendChild(dato);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por Contestar @Klaimmore, me ha sido de mucha ayuda, efectivamente, la manera que propusiste funciona como lo esperaba, ya tengo solucionado cuando la cantidad de datos sean mas que la cantidad de cabeceras. Muchísimas gracias